# Solving an exponential equation for an unknown base or exponent value

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Eg: $b^7=27$

Does there exist a logarithmic rule that I may use to solve for the value of $b$ or if the exponent was unknown and we already knew the value of the base?

Comment: I guess you don't like $b=27^{1/7}$? Unless, of course, this is an equation for $b\in\Bbb C$, in which case you need to consider all seven roots of $T^7-27$. But then logarithms are even worse...

Comment: i didnt know it or why it works, but still looking for a logarithmic reasoning.

Comment: For $~b,s \in \Bbb{R^+}, ~r \in \Bbb{R_{\neq 0}}:$ $$\log_b(s) = r \iff b^r = s \iff e^{r\ln(b)} = s = e^{\ln(s)}$$ $$\iff \ln(b) = \frac{\ln(s)}{r} \iff b = e^{\left[\frac{\ln(s)}{r}\right]} = s^{(1/r)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

*"Does there exist a logarithmic rule that I may use to solve for the value of $b$?"*

You might want to try the change of base law.

*"If the exponent was unknown and we already knew the value of the base?"*

Unless an exact value is not required, you can only express it as a logarithm, otherwise, you will need to solve it numerically.